# Italy, road network shapefile with full speed information

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, data, road, italy

I am perusing the internet since one day and still cannot find something satisfying.
The most important thing I am interested in is the speed limit (or an average speed) of the respective elements. I don't need information on small residential streets or city-level streets. Just the main road network would be enough.
The extracted **OSM** stuff I downloaded from [geofabrik.de](http://www.geofabrik.de) or [OSM extract Italy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) has tons of missing speed values and is thus not useful for me.

The closest I could get was the [NASA SEDAC](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/groads-global-roads-open-access-v1/data-download) Global Roads Open Access Data. I subsetted on Italy via a GADM0 shapefile, it's slim, only with main roads, but there is no speed information.
I found [this](http://product.itoworld.com/map/35?lon=13.24556&lat=43.12127&zoom=7) page with information on speed limits, but a manual editing would be virtually impossible.

Even a file that has **consistent and complete** (in the files I have, half of the roads go as "unclassified" - even though some of them are highways) information on the category of the street would be kind of o.k. In this case I could just impute average values for each type of street; which would be enough for the type of rough estimates of travel times I need.

Does anyone have a shapefile or information that could potentially help me?

Comment: Try ask at [opendata.se] Site

Answer (score 2):

You may download road network data about Italy using the "WFS Services" of the National Geoportal, following this link:

[Catalog Service WFS - The National Geoportal](http://www.pcn.minambiente.it/GN/en/accesso-ai-servizi-eng/servizi-di-download-eng/wfs-eng)

and using the URL from "Infrastrutture stradali".
These data haven't any information about speed limits but, if you don't need to perform a very accurate analysis, you could retrieve some information from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_Italy).

Comment: Thanks to you for the visit, I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: off topic: the raster from the even spaced points looks like you are also working with satellite light images

Comment: Actually, that raster was a clip from a digital terrain model ;-)

Comment: Did the "Infrastrutture stradali" get moved to somewhere else? I cannot find it following this instructions.